# jack_connect MIDI (Alsa) ports

Tags: linux, audio, midi, alsa, jack

I am having a hard time, figuring how can I instruct jack to connect 2 ALSA (MIDI) ports.

I can do it no problem, through qjackctl. And also use `jack_connect`  to connect 2 audio ports using.
Now I cannot get `jack_lsp` to show the ALSA ports and I cannot figure out how to refer correctly to the ALSA ports.

In qjackctl the ports that I wish to connect through the command line, appear as:

```
Ouput Ports

14:Midi Through  
  0:Midi Through Port-0

 -------------------------
 Input Ports

 128: SuperCollider
    0:in0
```

Any ideas?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Found out how. Just need to use `aconnect` ALSA sequencer connection manager.

To connect 14:0 to 128:0: `aconnect 14:0 128:0`
Disconnect: `aconnect -d 14:0 128:0`

Answer (score 0):

In SuperCollider, you can do

```
MIDIIn.connect(inport, device)
```

Inport is 0..(n-1) where 'n' is the number of input ports you created with `MIDIClient.init()`. Device may be a uid or an index into `MIDIClient.sources`.

Confirmed that `MIDIIn.connect` connections do show up in qjackctl.